# Plotting large datasets as kind=bar ineffective

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, python-ggplot

I am working with a semi-large data set of approx 100,000 records.  When I plot a df column as a line with the code below the plot takes approx 2 seconds.

```
with plt.style.context('ggplot'):
    plt.figure(3,figsize=(16,12))
    plt.subplot(411)
    df_pca_std['PC1_resid'].plot(title ="PC1 Residual", color='r')

    #If I change the plot to a bar (no other change)
    df_X_std['PC1_resid'].plot(**kind='bar'**, title ="PC1 Residual", color='r')
```

it takes 112 seconds and the render changes like this (jumbled x axis):

[image]

[image]

I have suppressed the axis and changed the style but neither helped. Anyone have ideas how to better render and take less time? The data being plotted is being checked for mean reversion and is better displayed as bar plot.

Comment: It's probably because it's trying to plot *100,000 bars*. That's a bit ridiculous...

Comment: 100k records ridiculous?  Not in my industry.  I can plot 1 million bars in Excel. Yes, Excel.  Why not some plotting tool in python then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure whatever you got in Excel was not 1 million bars. Let's just do the math: if your screen is 72 pixels per inch and you manage to plot exactly one vertical bar per horizontal pixel, to plot 1 million of those bars your plot would end up being over 1000 feet long.

Comment: When plotting that much data, there is some sort of averaging going on, either directly by you or under the hood by whatever plotting mechanism.

Comment: Fair comment.  I do not disagree.  Perhaps I should have worded my question as to how to do the averaging explicitly with matplotlib or what plotting library to use that would do it for me.

Comment: Fair enough.  Since you are using a pandas DataFrame you can probably look into some built-in pandas functionality to appropriately smooth the relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best charts visually but at least it renders.  Plotted 2.1 million bars in 14.2 secs.

```
import pygal                                                      
bar_chart = pygal.Bar()                                            
bar_chart.add('PC1_residuals',df_X_std['PC1_resid'])                        
bar_chart.render_to_file('bar_chart.svg')
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:  I do not actually need to plot bars but can use the very fast line plot and the 'fill_between' attribute to color the plot from zero to the line.  The effect is similar to plotting all the bars in a fraction of the time.

Use pydatetime method of DatetimeIndex to convert Date (the df index) to an array of datetime.datetime's that can be used by matplotlib then change the plot.

```
plotDates = mpl.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())

plt.fill_between(plotDates,0,df_pca_std['PC1_resid'], alpha=0.5)
```